# Do Humans Have a Biological Need for Hierarchies?

Tags: social-psychology

If I understand correctly, Jordan Peterson argues in *12 Rules for Life: An Antidote to Chaos* that hierarchy is natural and humans tend to form hierarchies.

Are there any studies to confirm or infirm this statement?

Comment: While I look for better sources, there is https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/under-the-influence/201210/status-hierarchies-do-we-need-them which hints that it is possible

Comment: Peterson is especially skilled in saying things that sound true without making any effort to back them up. Good to question them.

Comment: Read about Maslow's hierarchies

Comment: [There is a question asking for counterexamples to this.](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9165) Would you find it relevant?

Comment: @BryanKrause 3 years forward and this statement is like it's saying about AI-generated answers

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can be of help concerning your question about hierarchy: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5494206/

Comment: StackExchange answers should be self-contained; it's important and useful to reference sources, but we don't want link-only answers. Someone must be able to understand the answer standing on its own. Links should support the answer, not replace it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).